# AWS SNS push notification request returns "DeviceTokenNotForTopic"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

iOS app requests Token and sends it to the python API. I add it to AWS API as a device token and subscribe to the topic.

Then trying to send push notification I receive "**DeviceTokenNotForTopic**" error like this:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageMD5Sum": "71f457fe91ebc62efdce2acc25406ec8",
        "messageId": "6124ef9c-860d-561a-94fa-b98e2392fd2a",
        "topicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:all",
        "timestamp": "2019-10-05 14:06:23.427"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "deliveryId": "................",
        "destination": "...............",
        "providerResponse": "{\"reason\":\"DeviceTokenNotForTopic\"}",
        "dwellTimeMs": 145,
        "attempts": 1,
        "token": "............",
        "statusCode": 400
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error **"DeviceTokenNotForTopic"** is usually returned to SNS from APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) side.

If we look through the [APNS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html) docs, you'll see that this error mainly occurs when **"The device token does not match the specified topic"** where the "topic" refers to the bundle ID of the application. This would mean either :

**a)**. The tokens were not generated for that particular bundle id.

**b)**. When the bundle ID in the certificate used to authenticate with APNS does not match the device token's registered app, the endpoint on SNS becomes disabled because SNS is essentially saying *"Unless you change the device token, we won't be able to reach this endpoint"*.

Here's some tips for consideration in-case anyone else runs into this issue :

1. I would recommend to make sure the token is registered to the correct platform application if you have multiple iOS apps and confirm that the certificate is the correct certificate for that application environment.
2. If the iOS app was recently moved from sandbox to production, the certificates need to change as well and vice-versa is true.

Hope this helps.